# PHP optimize sql calls

Tags: php

There is 1 function in my application which is getting called multiple times. Every time it returns the same result. On a single page it is getting called 5 to 6 times. Is there any way I can reduce those calls, like store data in some variable and return the same if it is not empty.

Would appreciate any help.

Here is the function:

```
public function getResponse($connection)
{
    $query="select * from test order by date DSC";
    $arr = $connection ->query($query); //fetch all the data from query                   
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: You could not call it 5-6 times? Caching the result is rather simple, so what exactly is it you are asking?

Comment: from where is this function called? from inner php or ajax?

Comment: You've already answered your own question :-)

Comment: Inner PHP. Caching is the only option. Cant i store in class property. But every time i create the object, property gets reinitialized.

Comment: Try it with a `static` property.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. but when i make changes in table, how it would get reflected. Though it is very rare.

Comment: Either it returns the same result and you can cache it or it doesn't and you can't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this.

HOWEVER, you should't cache the response, you should capture the data (rows) out of the response.  Otherwise, you'll have pointer issues and other problems.  Instead, do whatever data conversion you want to do on the resultant rows, and store them in a similar manner.

```
private $_response_cache = null;
public function getResponse($connection)
{
    if (is_null($this->_response_cache))
    {
        $query="select * from test order by date DSC";
        $this->_response_cache = $connection ->query($query); //fetch all the data from query                   
    }
    return $this->_response_cache;
}
```

---

If you need it statically, here... but even more warnings.  Static code is problematic outside of constructors and should be used with caution.  It screws with unit testing and can cause weird side effects -- there is a large school that suggests never using it, and although I don't subscribe to that school, I do recognize that improper usage is easy and dangerous.

```
private static $_response_cache = null;
public function getResponse($connection)
{
    if (is_null(self::$_response_cache))
    {
        $query="select * from test order by date DSC";
        self::$_response_cache = $connection ->query($query); //fetch all the data from query                   
    }
    return self::$_response_cache;
}
```

Comment: Hi John, I dont want static variable. In your first snipate. whenever i will create the class object the if condition will always be executed..

Comment: Well, if you create 10 instances, all 10 instances will have to run it.  That's why we'd have to do it statically.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you've already answered the question, but if you're new to PHP then you use code such as:

```
// define variable
$response = null;

// then everywhere you're currently calling it, you could use:
$response = ($response == null) ? getResponse($conn) : $response;
```

Basically this checks if the variable is already holding the value returned from the function (ie has it been called already) and if so, uses that value otherwise calls the function and stores the returned value in the variable $response.

Hope this helps :)